Epimenides paradox inside arithmetic
I am currently reading "Gödel, Escher, Bach", and in the book author makes the following statement:

I think the Tarski reproduction of the [liar's] paradox inside TNT points the way to a deeper understanding of the nature of the [liar's] paradox in English. -- GEB, p. 584

Here TNT, is a formal system of arithmetic similar to Peano arithmetic. The way I see it, this sentence is wrong, no? According to Tarski, the truth predicate is not definable and the liar's paradox definition depends on it. So it is too not definable.

Not clear... the gist of Tarski's theory is that if we want to have a language with a truth predicate, this will reproduce the Liar. Thus , the solution is to build a hierarchy of languages where the truth-predicate for language L1 is defined in language L2, and so on.

Hofstadter is being informal here, what he means is that TNT enriched by the truth predicate reproduces the Liar in a simpler and more precise context, see IEP:"Tarski added precision to the discussion of the Liar by focusing not on a natural language such as English but on a classical, interpreted, formal language powerful enough to express at least elementary arithmetic... he was able to prove that Convention T, plus the assumption that the language contains its own concept of truth, produces semantic incoherence."

You see, Tarski's Undefinability Theorem is a bit of a buzzkill for formal systems. It says, quite plainly, that a system can't define a function that can determine the truth of its own statements. And TNT, despite its impressive power, is still a formal system. So, no truth predicate for TNT, no matter how clever you try to be. The author might be referring to some sort of representation of the Liar's Paradox within TNT, but that's not a true definition of a truth predicate. It's like saying you've "reproduced" a painting by drawing a stick figure of it. It's a representation, but it misses t

@MauroALLEGRANZA but based on the Post's theorem, the truth predicate can't be defined because otherwise the whole arithmetical hierarchy would collapse and that is not possible. So the truth predicate can't be defined in arithmetic not because it would produce the liar's paradox, it simply can't be defined.

@spacemonkey - Perhaps this helps to clarify it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem#History
Quoting from there:
"Smullyan (1991, 2001) has argued forcefully that Tarski's undefinability theorem deserves much of the attention garnered by Gödel's incompleteness theorems. That the latter theorems have much to say about all of mathematics and more controversially, about a range of philosophical issues (e.g., Lucas 1961) is less than evident. ..."


What Tarski found was that his version of the paradox has two distinct levels to it. On one level, it is a sentence about itself which would be true if it were false, and false if it were true. On the other level-which I like to call the arithmetical substrate-it is a sentence about integers which is true if and only if false.
Now for some reason this latter bothers people a lot more than the former. Some
people simply shrug off the former as "meaningless", because of its self-referentiality. But you can't shrug off paradoxical statements about integers. Statements about integers simply cannot be both true and false.
-- Douglas R. Hofstadter (1987)

The two sentences of Hofstadter I put in bold imply that you can shrug off paradoxical statements when they are not "about integers" because (according to Hofstadter) they can be both true and false. This doesn't makes any sense. No statement can be both true and false, period. Whether it is about numbers or not is totally irrelevant.
The book seems to have really impressed a lot of people, but the film Alien also did.

Did you miss the subjunctive mood there, "would be true"? Tarski's argument makes assumptions about the language that formulates the paradox, superficially appealing, and concludes by rejecting one of them exactly because "no statement can be both true and false". It is analogous to a producing number that is both even and odd in some 'arithmetic' and concluding that it is no good as arithmetic. This is how proofs by contradiction generally go.

@Conifold "Did you miss the subjunctive mood there" You missed the fact that I put the two offending sentences my comment is about in bold. So my answer isn't about Tarski's paper, although it is no good, but about Hofstadter's implied suggestion that you CAN shrug off paradoxical statements (as long as they are) NOT about integers because, according to him, those can be both true and false.

According to him, right before your boldface, "some people simply shrug off the former as "meaningless"". And even according to "some people", statements that are "both true and false" (whatever that means) are meaningless.

@Speakpigeon - It seems that any mention of the Liar triggers so much passion in you that you fail to see that Hofstadter is vehemently agreeing with the core of your first paragraph...

@Conifold Conifold, I have to give up here. I have no idea what your point is. My point is really very simple, but you apparently don't understand it either, Yet, as I just explained to you, the phrase in bold implies that that you CAN shrug off paradoxical statements (as long as they are) NOT about integers, because, according to Hofstadter, those can be both true and false. If you don't understand this, I don't understand why you don't, so unless you articulate your thought, we better stop here.

Your point is easy to understand, but the phrase in bold does not imply your premise. Instead, according to Hofstadter, "some people" shrug off some paradoxical statements (not about integers, and  specifically the Liar) because those are "meaningless". What "both true and false", or even just true, means as applied to meaningless sentences is not very clear, but is moot anyway because Hofstadter does not side with "some people". His focus on integers is there simply because even "some people" would not shrug off paradoxes concerning integers. It allows him to avoid belaboring a moot point.

@mudskipper "It seems that any mention of the Liar triggers so much passion in you" Don't be silly. It is not "any mention", it is absurd assertions. 2. "that you fail to see that Hofstadter is vehemently agreeing with the core of your first paragraph" Certainly not. My first paragraph says that Hofstadter is talking nonsense because he is implying that statements not about numbers can be both true and false, and this is absurd. He says this because he thinks the Liar is really a logical paradox, and this shows he doesn't understand logic.

@Speakpigeon - How do you know Hofstadter is using the word "logic" in the same way as you want to use it (or with the meaning that you give it)? If he is using it in another way, what is it that makes his use (or meaning) so wrong that you can assert he "doesn't understand logic"?  (You might say this is because of Hs way of talking about the Liar, but isn't your implicit argument then a circular argument?)

@Conifold "Your point is easy to understand" I would have thought so, but apparently you still don't understand it. -2. "the phrase in bold does not imply your premise." Oh yes it does. - 3. "*Instead, according to Hofstadter, "some people" shrug off . . . *" The point about "some people" is irrelevant. The two sentences in bold are clear enough.

@mudskipper "How do you know Hofstadter is using the word "logic" in the same way as you want to use it" Aristotle has defined the word "logic" without ambiguity. The 2,500 years of the Aristotelian tradition tells us that logicians during this time all understood what Aristotle said. The basic concepts are as self-evident as the validity of Aristotle's syllogisms. There is no room for interpretation. What is left to do is to explain how logic really works and academic logicians have made no progress since Aristotle.

Isn't it strange that after 2500 years, all (?) mathematicians and all what you call so-called logicians suddenly didn't understand "logic" anymore? It went fine for 2500 years, and suddenly everyone (apart from a select few real logicians perhaps?) lost their mind?

Since you are directly disagreeing apparently I did understand your point, lack of understanding cannot be disagreed with. Reading sentences out of context is generally not a good idea, but even these two sentences in isolation trivially do not entail what you infer. Reading the rest of the section makes it even clearer because Hofstadter plainly agrees with your point. Btw, if you read more of him you may find that the two of you are not that far apart on many other issues.

@mudskipper "Isn't it strange that after 2500 years, all (?) mathematicians (...) suddenly didn't understand "logic" anymore?" You would need to study the history of this pseudo-logic to understand why exactly, but there is nothing bizarre. You can drive for hours without accident and then suddenly veer off road on your own. And I also never said that Aristotelian logic was all good either. Aristotle himself got off the road at some point. 2. "lost their mind?" No; On the contrary. They deliberately drove off road! They thought it was, in their own words, "more convenient".
